# Add index numbers when converting sorted table to dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a vector of strings that I'm trying to convert into a data frame with a frequency column. So far so good, but when I `dim` my data frame, I get only one column instead of two. I guess R is using the words as the index values.

Anyway here is how it starts. My list:

```
a<-c("welcoming", "whatsyourexcuse", "whiteway", "zero", "yay", "whatsyourexcuse", "yay")
```

Then, I tried to sort the frequency values in decreasing order and store as data frame using:

```
df <- as.data.frame(sort(table(a), decreasing=TRUE))
```

Problem is when I `dim(df)` I get `[1] 5 1` instead of `[1] 5 2`. Here is what `df` looks like:

```
sort(table(a), decreasing = TRUE)

whatsyourexcuse                                  2
yay                                              2
welcoming                                        1
whiteway                                         1
zero                                             1
```

instead of:

```
    a                                             Freq
[1] whatsyourexcuse                                  2
[2] yay                                              2
[3] welcoming                                        1
[4] whiteway                                         1
[5] zero                                             1
```

Any pointers please? Thanks.

Comment: You could of course just do it in two steps. `df <- as.data.frame(table(a)) ; df[order(-df[2]), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(plyr)
a1 <- count(a)
a1[order(-a1$freq),]
#                 x freq
# 2 whatsyourexcuse    2
# 4             yay    2
# 1       welcoming    1
# 3        whiteway    1
# 5            zero    1
dim(a1)
#[1] 5 2
```

Or

```
 a2 <- stack(sort(table(a),decreasing=TRUE))[,2:1]
 dim(a2)
 #[1] 5 2
```

When you are converting to data.frame using `as.data.frame(sort(table(a), decreasing=TRUE))`, the names of the elements become the `rownames` of the dataframe, so you are creating only one column instead of two.  When you do `sort`, it no longer is the `table` object.  For comparison check `str(table(a))` and `str(sort(table(a), decreasing=TRUE)))`

You can also create the `data.frame` by

```
 tbl <- sort(table(a), decreasing=TRUE)
 data.frame(col1= names(tbl), Values= as.vector(tbl))
```